# Cannot resolve 'R' due to conflict in version

Tags: android, android-studio

In my gradle, I have a conflict in versions that gives me the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'` but I don't know what is the wrong version.

In my gradle, I have a conflict in versions that gives me the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'` but I don't know what is the wrong version.

Already tried every other solution:

- Clean and Rebuild project
- Sync project
- Clean cache

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  ```
  android {
      compileSdkVersion 26
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.example.ves.gennaio3"
          minSdkVersion 14
          targetSdkVersion 26
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
      implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
      compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
      compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it

Comment: Clean cache and remove the gradle folder in project.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel already done. Already synced and tried everything.

Comment: Updating the SupportLibrary to `28.0.0` and replacing `compile` with  `implementation` and after, cleaning project will help I hope. Even if it didn't there must be other issues in the project which you need to give us more infor or any helpful logs-screenshots.

Comment: If you have a conflict in version you should get an error for that version. The R issue can also be caused by an error in the XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You cloud try the following: 
**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart Android Studio -> Invalidate and Restart**

Android Studio maintains  information about which files are dependent on which other files. This means you not only have to Gradle sync your files, but you also need to invalidate studio caches.

Comment: If that doesn’t work the build should have more info on what is happening. Try running this on the terminal: ./gradlew assembleDebug —stacktrace